# react redux doesn't update immediately and shows the last update?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

I have two select inputs with 3 categories, that depending on the one that you choose, the sub category input options are going to be different.

This is my slice:

```
    const initialState: SubCategoryTyped = {
  value: 'Escolha a categoria redux',
  subCategories: []
}

const ProgrammingOpt = [{option1: 'Front-end', option2: 'Back-end', option3: 'Mobile'}];
const DesignOpt = [{option1:  'UI Design', option2: 'UX Design', option3: 'Web design'}];
const MarketingOpt = [{option1: 'Social media', option2: 'Copywriting', option3: 'ADS'}];


 const sliceCategory = createSlice({
  name: "category",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    addCategory: (state, action: PayloadAction<string>) => {
      state.value = action.payload;
      switch (state.value) {
        case 'Programaçao':
          state.subCategories = ProgrammingOpt;
          state.subCategories;
          break;
          case 'Design':
            state.subCategories = DesignOpt;
          state.subCategories;
          break;
            case 'Marketing':
              state.subCategories = MarketingOpt;
              state.subCategories;
      }
    },
  }
});

export const { addCategory } = sliceCategory.actions;

export default sliceCategory.reducer;
```

and store:

```
    import sliceCategory from './SliceCategory'

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    category: sliceCategory,
  }
})

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>
export type addDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;
```

Everytime I log subCategories it only shows the array of the last chosen option, for example when I click on programming, it shows nothing, but when i click in other option, lets say - marketing, it is going to show the array of the programmings options.

What can I do?

Comment: Maybe an immediate update not happen for  state.value. You can try switch (action.payload)

Comment: Just tried action payload and it goes the same as state value.